# CompletableFuture with PriorityBlockingQueue

Tags: java, java-8, concurrency

I am trying to write a Single Thread Executor that returns a `CompletableFuture` when a task gets scheduled and executes the task based on a `PriorityBlockingQueue`.

My Tasks look like this:

```java
  public interface DriverTask<V> {

    V call(WebDriver driver) throws Throwable;

    default TaskPriority getPriority() {
      return TaskPriority.LOW;
    }
  }

  public enum TaskPriority {
    HIGH,
    MEDIUM,
    LOW
  }
```

Now my problem is when I use the `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync` Method the Executor only gets a `Runnable` and I dont know how to get my Executor to know the priority of the original Task.

Is there a different way to create a `CompletableFuture` so that I get execute them based on priority?

Comment: I can simply complete a CompletableFuture in your own ExecutorService. Just Execute the work in your ExecutorService and call .complete() this way u can write code that would does work based on Priority....

Comment: @Alex would i just create the future via the constructor and then call complete() on it when it was executed? Or is there something else i have to keep in mind.

Comment: Yes that was my idea ;D

Comment: There are additional obstacles, like throwing `Throwable` or needing a `WebDriver`, which make `supplyAsync` infeasible. Who is supposed to provide the argument, the caller or the executor?

Comment: @Holger I did it by constructing a `Supplier` from the `DriverTask` that would call the `DriverTask` with the `WebDriver` to supply the value. Throwables thrown by the `DriverTask` would get wrapped in a `CompletitionException` in the `Supplier`.

Comment: So the `WebDriver` is provided by the caller which also provided the `DriverTask` or is it some (global) variable that is in scope?

Comment: @Holger no sorry, the Executor that has a `#schedule(DriverTask)` method has the `WebDriver` object. And in order to actually schedule the task the Executor would construct a `Supplier` from the `DriverTask`, giving the `Supplier` a reference to the `WebDriver`, which would then call the `DriverTask` with the `WebDriver` to get the value.

Comment: So the executor knows the `WebDriver`. Can I assume, e.g. a method `currDriver()` for the sake of an example solution?

Comment: @Holger yes, sure!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The principle of methods like `supplyAsync` is to create a new `CompletableFuture` instance an setting up and asynchronous job which will eventually `complete` the future.

You can do the same for your nontrivial setup:

```
private static WebDriver currentDriver() {
    …
}
private static final ExecutorService BACKEND
    = new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, 1, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES, new PriorityBlockingQueue<>());

public static <V> CompletableFuture<V> runAsync(DriverTask<V> dt) {
    CompletableFuture<V> result = new CompletableFuture<>();
    class Job implements Runnable, Comparable<Job>,
                         CompletableFuture.AsynchronousCompletionTask {
        public void run() {
            try {
                if(!result.isDone()) result.complete(dt.call(currentDriver()));
            }
            catch(Throwable t) { result.completeExceptionally(t); }
        }
        private TaskPriority priority() { return dt.getPriority(); }
        public int compareTo(Job o) { return priority().compareTo(o.priority()); }
    }
    BACKEND.execute(new Job());
    return result;
}
```

Note that implementing `CompletableFuture.AsynchronousCompletionTask` is not necessary; it’s just a convention for marking those `Runnable` implementations whose purpose is to complete a `CompletableFuture`.

Another advantage of implementing the logic yourself is that this first stage does not need to wrap exceptions in a `CompletionException`. So when the caller chains an `exceptionally`, it will see the original, unwrapped exception. Also, a caller of `join` would get a `CompletionException` reflecting the code location of the `join` call with the original exception as the cause, carrying much more useful information.

The purpose of `if(!result.isDone())` before the actual completion attempt is to skip it if the `CompletableFuture` has been cancelled (or otherwise completed) while waiting in the queue. Once the completion attempt has been started, canceling won’t interrupt it. This is the general behavior of `CompletableFuture`.

Comment: Thank you for taking so much time to help me with this. I implemented it the way you showed here but I'm still trying to fully understand it.

Since the execute method of `ThreadPoolExecutor` just takes a `Runnable` how does the executor make sure the order of execution is actually based on priority? Does the underlying PriorityBlockingQueue just assume the `Runnable` is also a `Comparable`? Are there no type safety issues?

Comment: Yes, the `PriorityBlockingQueue` assumes comparable elements. It’s a weakness of the type system, we have with all sorted collections (`TreeSet` etc. as well), when using the default constructor, in other words neither a comparator nor initial values have been specified. Note that this works the same as `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor​`, except that our priority is not time based.